# wp_signon not working, as moving to next page gives me no user logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress project I am have created template page where user can register. Now Problem I am facing is making user logged in after registration. I have created a user and after that I have tried to make the user log in using below code.

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

I have also created a log in template to allow user loged in by using same above code but same issues occurs. Now problem I am facing is as soon as I moved to new page, I found user is not logged in.

I guess cookies are not getting saved. I have also tried using

```
wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID,true);
```

But no success.

I cannot understand when we logged in using wp-admin then one can successfully logged in or if I am using wp_login_form() then that also works fine. Then wats is the problem by using above code.

Please help as I have to anyhow make user logged in after registration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is correct. Both pieces of code will authenticate and login the user succesfully.

However you are missing the redirect. After calling wp_signon() or wp_set_auth_cookie(), you should redirect the user to make sure the new cookie is being loaded.

This can be done by using the following code right after your wp_signon() or wp_set_auth_cookie() call:

```
wp_redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
```

In case you want to redirect the user to a specific page, you can replace `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with the URL where you want to redirect the user to.

A sidenote: you should make sure that this code is called before the headers are being sent, as wp_redirect() will not work after the headers are sent.

**EDIT:** In case the above does not work, you might try the entire login process (`$user` should be the user object, which you can get with the `get_user_by()` function):

```
do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
$redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
exit;
```

Comment: Glad to see your reply as I am higly frustrated now. I am redirecting after login.

Comment: My code execution sequnce is...1) Getting values from request 2) registring user 3) making user login 4) sending the mail to user 5) redirecting to success page by java script.. So before login I am not printing anything

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain a solution that i've used in my previous projects and it worked correctly. You can feel free to try using it, and make sure that `$user` contains your user object (which can be received by get_user_by() function). Also, using wp_redirect() is always better than JS redirection, so I recommend using wp_redirect().

Comment: I tried above as well, wp_redirect() and wp_safe_redirect() both fails to redirect the page, thats why I am using JS

Comment: If they are failing to redirect, this means that your headers have been sent already. If your headers are already sent, this is probably the reason why your wp_set_auth_cookie() and wp_signon() does not work. So you should make sure that you're executing this code very early, before anything is being output at all. An option is to hook this code on an action, like template_redirect or wp_loaded.

Comment: I guess true..Headers are may be sent..but I dont what do you mean by code very early?.. I already mentioned my code execution sequence above.

Comment: Also, I am submitting the form to same page, so in the beginning I just check whether this is $_POST request or not.. is that can be a problem.

Comment: I see where your confusion goes. Can you please tell me where are you starting this sequence? Where are you starting 1)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60562/discussion-between-mahesh-and-marin-atanasov).

Comment: You are awesome..You gave your time..but you solved the problem..I am happy with your support

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed issues by making true in the following function

`$user = wp_signon( $creds, true );`